# How can I convert `Slot` to `TokenName`

Tags: plutus, haskell

I feel like this should be pretty easy, but I'm stumped. How can I use a slot number as a token name?

I'm currently trying to `encode` the slot `integer` as a `ByteString`:

```
slotNumberTokenName :: TokenName
slotNumberTokenName = TokenName { unTokenName = encode $ getSlot slot }
```

but I get the error

```
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘ByteString’
                  with actual type ‘bytestring-0.10.12.0:Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString’
      NB: ‘bytestring-0.10.12.0:Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString’
            is defined in ‘Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal’
          ‘ByteString’ is defined in ‘Data.ByteString.Internal’
    • In the ‘unTokenName’ field of a record
      In the expression: TokenName {unTokenName = encode $ getSlot slot}
      In an equation for ‘slotNumberTokenName’:
          slotNumberTokenName
            = TokenName {unTokenName = encode $ getSlot slot}
    |
153 |     slotNumberTokenName = TokenName { unTokenName = encode $ getSlot slot }
    |
```

I am using `Data.Aeson.encode`, so maybe there is a different function to do that conversion.

Anyhow, any help would be appreciated. Been looking at this for longer than I'd like to admit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just run this in the REPL with success. Not sure if it is the best way, though.

```
TokenName { unTokenName = Data.ByteString.Char8.pack $ show (toInteger (getSlot 1)) }
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks. I agree there might be a more direct way of doing it, but I'm not picky for now. Can always improve it.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `Data.Binary`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2284193/10069673

Another possibility would be to convert the `int` to a `string` and then convert the `string` to a `ByteString`.

- `int` to `string`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2784280/10069673
- `string` to `ByteString`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40491001/10069673

Comment: Hmm. I got the same error with `Data.Binary.encode` as I got with `Data.Aeson.encode`. Seems like it would work :/ I got Chrismo's suggestion to work though. Thanks!